# The side of a square is increasing at a rate of 5cm/s. At what rate is the area changing when the side is 10 cm long? Question continued below..

Tags: calculus

.... At what rate is the perimeter changing when the side is 10cm long?

I am not very good at these related rate questions so if anyone could help me through it that would be great.

From what i know and if i am correct, this is what i have so far..

ds/dt = 5
A = s^2

Let A be area in cm, Let s be the length of the side, Let t be the time in seconds

So we are looking for dA/dt when s = 10? If i am correct? 
If so then would this be the formula?

dA/dt = d/dt (s^2) = 2s(ds/dt)?

Now i am a little confused.

Comment: That's it.Rate of change of area when side is 10 cm long is 2 * 10 * ds/dt = 2 * 10 * 5

Comment: Now you need to evaluate $\frac{dA}{dt}$ at the instant when $s=10$.

Comment: Why on earth are you confused.  Everything you said is correct and makes perfect sense.  So go on.... ds/dt = 5 so dA/dt = 2s (5) and.....

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for the reassurance!

Comment: @Jessica: You can use the same sort of calculation. However, for the perimeter question we really do not need calculus: If the side is increasing at $5$ cm/s, then the perimeter is increasing at $20$ cm/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A=s^2\implies {dA\over dt}={d\over dt}(s^2)=2s{ds\over dt}=2\times 10\times 5=100$$

Answer (score 0):

Let x be the side of square.
dA/dt = 0.5 cm2/s 
Area of square = x square
 dA/dt = 2x dx/dt
0.5 = 2(10) dx/dt 
0.5/20 = dx/dt
Perimeter of square = 4x
 P = 4x
dp/dt = 4 dx/dt
           =  4 (0.5 /20)
           = 0.1 cm /s
    By prof. Siddhesh indulkar ( rugved classes )

Comment: [Here is a quick tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format your post.